# looking for idioms that mean to look at something old in a new way

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Need an idiom that connotes the idea of seeing something in a way you've never seen it before. Something along the lines of "shining a new light on an old [something]" or "seeing an old [object] through a new lense". Or maybe even something that communicates the idea of appreciating something about a thing/person you never appreciated. Mainly though I want something that puts emphasis on the fact that you've been "looking at it wrong" the entire time.

Comment: You're close: 'see something in a new light'.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at something ***with a new [perspective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspective)***:

> the capacity to view things in their true relations or relative importance.

(M-W)